# R Studio Server shortcut for closing current tab

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio-server

I am searching for the shortcut to just close the current tab in the server version of R Studio.
Ctrl+W is occupied by the browser. Ctrl+Shft+W closes all browser tabs. Cltr+Alt+W does nothing and Ctrl+Shft+Alt+W closes all R tabs without the current one.

Is there btw a shortcut to undo the last combination?

Comment: Try Alt+Shift+K. This will give you all shortcuts!

Comment: Thanks, but not finding it there, is one of the reasons why I'm asking. Does it not exist?

Comment: Maybe after looking at ctlr + shift + p use Ctrl + w?

Comment: Interesting, R suggests Close Document literally in the first place after ctrl+shift+p and even suggests ctrl+w as shortcut. However, pressing ctrl+w after this combination still leads to a closed browser tab. So, it looks like the currently best solution I have is to go with ctrl+shft+p and just press enter afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suitable workaround was to just change the shortcut. R Studio allows to set own shortcuts and modify existing ones in the menu. Just go to the toolbar and on "Tools\Modify Keyboard Shortcuts...". I simply set it to Ctrl+Alt+W, because that's unused and somewhat consistent to the fact, that Ctrl+Alt+Shft+W closes all documents that are opened in R Studio, by default.